# ios9 updated iPad now wants passcode already tried restore

Tags: ipad, backup, restore

I recently updated to ios9 and it now wants a passcode.  I've tried to restore via DFU mode, however iTunes no longer lets you JUST "restore" - you now have to "Restore & Update" which puts me right back to needing a passcode.  I either never set one up, or it was 10 years ago when I first go the iPad.  My apple ID and other "usual" passcodes I might have used don't work.  I tried a second time doing restore and now just get an error message.  Ideas??

Comment: "_needing a passcode_": iCloud `Activation Lock` passcode or original device passcode?

Comment: Tried using my Apple ID password, it didn't work.  Don't know that I have an original device passcode (either iPad is too old or I don't remember setting one up 10 years ago).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I got it...I noticed my iTunes would say there was no updated version available, but the latest version to download (new) from the website was a higher version number.  So I re-installed iTunes on my computer and it seemed to work!  Yay!

Answer (score 0):

The only option will be to wipe your iPad (restore it to factory settings). Apple talks about this on their support site: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306

You'll want to restore the phone, but not restore the backup.

Comment: I tried this.  :-(  Both in Restore mode and DFU mode.  Sometimes I get error message "The iPad could not be restored. An unknown error occurred (3194)." or it restores, reboots, and then wants a passcode.  :-/